# Django form as table td with readonly fields

Tags: django, forms

I want to display all objects for model in a form with information as readonly fields in a table, with each field as a cell of the table.

Currently I can render a form around a table with all records...

```
In views: schedule_projects = Record.objects.all()

In template:

<form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Record</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Comment</th>
          <th colspan="2">Attached</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          {% for record in schedule_projects %}
            <tr>
               <td>{{record.projectname}}</td>
               <td>{{record.date_edited|date:"d-m-Y H:i"}}</td>
               <td>{% if record.project_details %}{{record.project_details}}{% else %}{%endif%}</td>
                <td>{{record.attached_files|default_if_none:'0'}}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="record" value="{{record.plan_delete}}"></td>    
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </table>
            <button type="submit" name="plan_delete">Add to delete schedule</button></form>
```

Instead of doing it manually like this, I wanted to do it with a form built in forms.py - as it offers validation, csrf and other methods.

I want the form to render each field without a label, and as readonly text fields, not as input fields. I also want the records that have the boolean field plan_delete=True to be activated with a tick if the value is true in the initial form, so that I can add more records with the plan_delete boolean in the view if the form is submitted. It should look like this.

```
Record        Date        Comment           Attached       
John Doe      01/02/2017  Current           3           (checkbox)
Peter Piper   02/01/2017  Bla. bla          5           (checkbox)
Etc..         11/12/2017  Etc..             0           (checkbox)

Add to delete schedule (submit)
```

I've tried playing around with form as_table, and modelform, but it seems that something so simple gets really complicated quite quickly.

So my question is, is my way the 'right', most simple way to do it - or am I missing quite something simple about benefits of forms.form or modelform added to forms.py? How do I go about rendering a form that contains all my records, and a checkbox for the plan_delete field - so that I can process it in my view.

Answer (score 0):

In your views you can make the GET function return a form with the widget attribute set to readonly, something like this: `self.fields['sku'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True`

Comment: I tried that too, it displays an input field greyed out for every field with a read only value inside, so I need to overwrite the type of widget and the attrs for every field. That's a lot of work, which brings me to my question - which is what the most simple way to do it is. Form also only still displays one object - and I want all objects in the form.

Comment: I would recommend that you use the django crispy form, it handles a lot of the heavy lifting, you can check out the documentation here:http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form_helper.html